# Why spring @Controller path '/' is not registered by spring boot in google appengine?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, google-app-engine

I have uploaded my maven, spring boot application to google app engine. My `pom.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.lumiin</groupId>
    <artifactId>gae-mytalk</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>gae</name>
    <description>mytalk</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <src.webapp.dir>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</src.webapp.dir>
        <app.version>${project.version}</app.version>
        <app.url>http://taxi2deal.appspot.com</app.url>
        <commons-lang3.version>3.3.2</commons-lang3.version>
        <maven.failsafe.version>2.17</maven.failsafe.version>
        <start-class>com.lumiin.mytalk.Application</start-class>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>/</m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>
        <hibernate-validator.version>4.3.2.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
        <!--<enunciate.version>1.27</enunciate.version>-->

        <gae.version>1.9.17</gae.version>
        <gae.home>${settings.localRepository}/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/${gae.version}/appengine-java-sdk/appengine-java-sdk-${gae.version}</gae.home>

        <gae.application.version>test</gae.application.version>
        <mockito.version>1.9.5</mockito.version>
        <rest-assured.version>2.0.0</rest-assured.version>
        <!-- <spring-security-oauth.version>2.0.8.RELEASE</spring-security-oauth.version> -->
        <!-- not sure if GAE supports these yet -->
        <!--<jetty.version>9.1.0.v20131115</jetty.version>-->
        <!--<servlet-api.version>3.1.0</servlet-api.version>-->
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>my-local-repo</id>
            <url>file://${basedir}/third_party</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>codelds</id>
            <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-repo</id>
            <name>mvn-repository</name>
            <url>http://mvnrepository.com</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>google-releases</id>
            <name>Google Releases</name>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/google-releases</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <snapshots />
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

    </repositories>

    <profiles>
        <!-- We can configure our integration server to activate this profile and
            perform gae:deploy, thus uploading latest snapshot to the http://1.latest.<applicationName>.appspot.com
            automatically -->
        <profile>
            <id>integration-build</id>
            <properties>
                <gae.application.version>stage</gae.application.version>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <!-- This profile will activate automatically during release and upload
            application to the http://2.latest.<applicationName>.appspot.com (We might
            want to set the 2nd version as our applications Default version to be accessible
            at http://<applicationName>.appspot.com) -->
        <profile>
            <id>release-build</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>performRelease</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
            </activation>

            <properties>
                <!-- During release, set application version in appengine-web.xml to
                    2 -->
                <gae.application.version>release</gae.application.version>
            </properties>
        </profile>

    </profiles>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-legacy</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- == Begin Google App Engine == -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${gae.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
            <version>${gae.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
            <version>${gae.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-tools-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${gae.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-labs</artifactId>
            <version>${gae.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- End Google App Engine-->




        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.objectify</groupId>
            <artifactId>objectify</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ganyo</groupId>
            <artifactId>geocell</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20140107</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.23</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>twilio-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.authy</groupId>
            <artifactId>authy-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mandrillapp.wrapper.lutung</groupId>
            <artifactId>lutung</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ganyo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gcm-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
             <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
             <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
             <version>1</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <outputDirectory>target/${project.artifactId}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>                    
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gae.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!--<enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>-->
                    <fullScanSeconds>-1</fullScanSeconds>                   
                </configuration>
             </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>




    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

My `web.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

     <filter>
        <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.lumiin.mytalk.Application</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web.SpringBootContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>publishEvents</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>

        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

As I understand starting point of my spring boot webapp is class `com.lumiin.mytalk.Application`. Here it is:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({ "com.lumiin.mytalk.controllers" })
public class Application
{
}
```

It should search for `@Controllers` in package `com.lumiin.mytalk.controllers`. I have single `@Controller` there:

```
package com.lumiin.mytalk.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

@Controller
public class GuestbookController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    String list(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "GuestbookController is called ura");
        System.out.println("GUESTBOOK CONTROLLER IS CALLED TO RETURN INDEX");
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/google", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    String toGoogle(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "GuestbookController is called ura");
        System.out.println("GUESTBOOK CONTROLLER IS CALLED TO RETURN INDEX");
        model.addAttribute("name", "volodia");
        return "greeting";
    }

}
```

I uploaded this to gae and try two urls: `/` and `/google`.
Url `google` is mapped and called correctly and logs are printed.

But url `/`, that is `applicationId.appspot.com/`, is not called and not registered. I expect method `GuestbookController.list` to be executed but it doesn't.

Why isn't '/' mapped by spring ?

Comment: Try `@RestController` instead of `@Controller`

Comment: I'm having sort of similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49648829/app-engine-java-8-servlet-3-1-and-web-xml where web.xml would change the way application is on the gcp appengine.